# How to set axios baseURL for VueJS app if backend is in the same docker container

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, flask, axios

I have the app deployed in one docker container:

1. **Frontend** - VueJS (served by Nginx)
2. **Backend** - Flask (gunicorn)

**Dockerfile:**

```
# Builder
FROM node:10-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /vue-ui
COPY ./frontend/package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./frontend .
RUN npm run build

#Production container
FROM nginx:alpine as production-build

WORKDIR /app
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache python3 && \
    python3 -m ensurepip && \
    rm -r /usr/lib/python*/ensurepip && \
    pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools && \
    if [ ! -e /usr/bin/pip ]; then ln -s pip3 /usr/bin/pip ; fi && \
    if [[ ! -e /usr/bin/python ]]; then ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python; fi && \
    rm -r /root/.cache
RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev libxslt-dev libffi-dev


COPY ./.nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
COPY --from=builder /vue-ui/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./backend/requirements.txt .
COPY ./backend/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install gunicorn
COPY ./backend .
ENV DB_URL_EXTERNAL=postgres://logpasstodb/maindb
#ENV DB_URL_EXTERNAL=$DB_URL_EXTERNAL
EXPOSE 80 5432
#ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
CMD gunicorn --chdir / -b 0.0.0.0:5000 app:create_app --daemon && \
      nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

When the frontend trying to send a request to the flask app, getting the following:

```
POST http://localhost:5000/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Axios `baseURL` set to `axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:5000/';`. Also, the same issue if its changed to docker internal host `172.17.0.2`.

The main thing is if I'm running the backend on my local machine, where docker container deployed, the application (frontend) can successfully connect to it.

**nginx.conf:**

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html index.htm;
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please suggest, how to set baseURL correctly or it could be the problem with Nginx confs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could add extra mapping into your NGINX conf

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_pass localhost:5000;
}
```

And then set baseUrl to localhost:80/api/

Answer (score 0):

You have exposed ports 80 and 5432, but not the port 5000 which is listened by backend application.

Expose port 5000 and set baseUrl to :5000